# Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";" What's wrong?

Tags: reactjs

What's wrong?

While i try to compile it i get error: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

code goes here:

```
<https://pastebin.com/GNbdiG9P>


import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import connect from '@vkontakte/vk-connect';
import View from '@vkontakte/vkui/dist/components/View/View';
import ConfigProvider from '@vkontakte/vkui/dist/components/ConfigProvider/ConfigProvider';
import '@vkontakte/vkui/dist/vkui.css';
import { Panel, PanelHeader, Tabbar, TabbarItem, Epic } from '@vkontakte/vkui';
import Icon28AddOutline from '@vkontakte/icons/dist/28/add_outline';
import Icon28NewsfeedOutline from '@vkontakte/icons/dist/28/newsfeed_outline';
import Icon28SettingsOutline from '@vkontakte/icons/dist/28/settings_outline';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
      super(props);

        this.state = {
            scheme: "space_gray"
        };
        this.scheme = this.scheme.bind(this);

      this.state = {
        activeStory: 'feed'
      };
      this.onStoryChange = this.onStoryChange.bind(this);

    onStoryChange (e) {
      this.setState({ activeStory: e.currentTarget.dataset.story })
    }
}
    render () {
      return (
        <Epic activeStory={this.state.activeStory} scheme={this.state.scheme} tabbar={
          <Tabbar>
            <TabbarItem
              onClick={this.onStoryChange}
              selected={this.state.activeStory === 'feed'}
              data-story="feed"
              text="Главная"
            ><Icon28NewsfeedOutline /></TabbarItem>
            <TabbarItem
              onClick={this.onStoryChange}
              selected={this.state.activeStory === 'add_skin'}
              data-story="add_skin"
              text="Добавить скин"
            ><Icon28AddOutline /></TabbarItem>
            <TabbarItem
              onClick={this.onStoryChange}
              selected={this.state.activeStory === 'settings'}
              data-story="settings"
              label="12"
              text="Настройки"
            ><Icon28SettingsOutline /></TabbarItem>
          </Tabbar>
        }>
          <View id="feed" activePanel="feed">
            <Panel id="feed">
              <PanelHeader>Главная</PanelHeader>
            </Panel>
          </View>
          <View id="add_skin" activePanel="add_skin">
            <Panel id="add_skin">
              <PanelHeader>Добавить скин</PanelHeader>
            </Panel>
          </View>
          <View id="settings" activePanel="settings">
            <Panel id="settings">
              <PanelHeader>Настройки</PanelHeader>
            </Panel>
          </View>
        </Epic>
      )
    }
}
  export default App;
```

Comment: show code here. pastebin is not secured

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some issues with your matching braces. This is how you should fix:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import connect from '@vkontakte/vk-connect';
import View from '@vkontakte/vkui/dist/components/View/View';
import ConfigProvider from '@vkontakte/vkui/dist/components/ConfigProvider/ConfigProvider';
import '@vkontakte/vkui/dist/vkui.css';
import { Panel, PanelHeader, Tabbar, TabbarItem, Epic } from '@vkontakte/vkui';
import Icon28AddOutline from '@vkontakte/icons/dist/28/add_outline';
import Icon28NewsfeedOutline from '@vkontakte/icons/dist/28/newsfeed_outline';
import Icon28SettingsOutline from '@vkontakte/icons/dist/28/settings_outline';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        scheme: 'space_gray',
        activeStory: 'feed'
      };
      this.scheme = this.scheme.bind(this);
      this.onStoryChange = this.onStoryChange.bind(this);
   }

    onStoryChange (e) {
      this.setState({ activeStory: e.currentTarget.dataset.story })
    }

    render () {
      return (
        <Epic activeStory={this.state.activeStory} scheme={this.state.scheme} tabbar={
          <Tabbar>
            <TabbarItem
              onClick={this.onStoryChange}
              selected={this.state.activeStory === 'feed'}
              data-story="feed"
              text="Главная"
            ><Icon28NewsfeedOutline /></TabbarItem>
            <TabbarItem
              onClick={this.onStoryChange}
              selected={this.state.activeStory === 'add_skin'}
              data-story="add_skin"
              text="Добавить скин"
            ><Icon28AddOutline /></TabbarItem>
            <TabbarItem
              onClick={this.onStoryChange}
              selected={this.state.activeStory === 'settings'}
              data-story="settings"
              label="12"
              text="Настройки"
            ><Icon28SettingsOutline /></TabbarItem>
          </Tabbar>
        }>
          <View id="feed" activePanel="feed">
            <Panel id="feed">
              <PanelHeader>Главная</PanelHeader>
            </Panel>
          </View>
          <View id="add_skin" activePanel="add_skin">
            <Panel id="add_skin">
              <PanelHeader>Добавить скин</PanelHeader>
            </Panel>
          </View>
          <View id="settings" activePanel="settings">
            <Panel id="settings">
              <PanelHeader>Настройки</PanelHeader>
            </Panel>
          </View>
        </Epic>
      )
    }
}
  export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to use a good editor for your code, by the way the problem is in this line:

```
    onStoryChange (e) {
      this.setState({ activeStory: e.currentTarget.dataset.story })
    }
} <-- this is the problem, move it before the function
```

Comment: now i have this error   Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Your `onStoryChange` should be outside the constructor. Moreover, believe `scheme` is not a method but a property in your case.

```
constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            scheme: "space_gray",
            activeStory: 'feed'
        };



}

onStoryChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({ activeStory: e.currentTarget.dataset.story })
    }
```

Comment: now i have this problem  Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined this.scheme = this.scheme.bind(this);
        this.onStoryChange = this.onStoryChange.bind(this);

Comment: @ПавелМерцалов Try now.

Comment: @ПавелМерцалов glad to help. Don't forget to mark it as answer if this was what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            scheme: "space_gray",
            activeStory: 'feed'
        };



}

onStoryChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({ activeStory: e.currentTarget.dataset.story })
    }
```

Thanks.